# Is it possible to scroll a long panel when AutoScroll=False on windows forms custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A workaround is adjusting a panel's location responding to the wheel, but it looks stupid.
This question is simple but I can't believe I just can't find the solution.

References: [ScrollToControl" with AutoScroll = false?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/da3509dc-3d5e-4590-9554-68acd1067c6d/quotscrolltocontrolquot-with-autoscroll-false?forum=winforms)

Comment: You can set the `VerticalScroll.Value` when `AutoScroll = false`, causing the Panel to scroll, but it won't have a nice effect: the scrollbars can pop sometimes, just a ghostly flicker, visible nonetheless. You'll have to *hide* the area they occupy anyway. So, you could just do that. IMO, the *Panel inside a Panel* method works better and it's easier to handle.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you could also PInvoke [ScrollWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindowex) (which also allow the set the smooth scroll feature).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can add for vertical scrolling a Windows Forms Standard Controll called
    VScrollBar 
into your Panel and for horizontal
    HScrollBar